# Detect IP User is on your site on their phone and desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile, synchronization, desktop, user-experience

Google had the Star Wars experience where you viewed the site on your desktop then on the phone. The phone controlled the lightsabre hilt and movement and the action took place on the desktop.

That is very involved as it was a mini game.
But in terms of the core functionality..

How and what is the best way to detect or sync a user on both their mobile device and desktop via your website.
I take it they will need to be on the same network otherwise you would have to do some code to type sync which would be a bit clunky.

Once connected how would you sync, so lets say you read the motion of the phone, how could you feed that to the desktop version of the site.

IF we take a basic principle..

Lets say we have some circles bouncing around on the desktop site and you have a big red one on your phone. You flick it and it appears on the desktop and if it hits a white circle the interaction.

The actual code on either device is fine, its the sync element and the best way to do it?

Comment: Well one way to do this would be WebRTC, which means that the devices would be connected directly to each other and you wouldn't need a server. Another way would be to connect 2 devices with the same IP to each other and hope there's not 2 people connecting from the same household.

Comment: Also this isn't a very code based question (more theoretical) which doesn't belong very well on SO.

Comment: Well code will be formed from it. This is not theory. Sites do it, I am looking for the codebase on how you achieve it. Every increasing feeling Stackoverflow is not really good for anything these days.

Comment: On the tour page ( http://stackoverflow.com/tour ) it states "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" which is why I'm saying that it's not a very good question for SO since you haven't done anything yet.

Comment: I think many of the rules, the type of comments on here, the attacks on people as well... I think this website is about done and soon as someone does something better good. Well I wont get help on here so I will keep looking myself.

Comment: Sorry dude, this isn't an attack on you ( I haven't even downvoted your question ) it's just a bad question for SO.